# How do I replace a showModalBottomSheet with another another modalBottomSheet?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart, modal-dialog

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, basically I have a method that calls the flutter showModalBottomSheet, now inside this modal there is a button that is supposed to open up another modalBottomSheet, my question is how do I make it that when the button is pressed inside the modal, the entire modal is replaced with a new modal, and not overlapped with the new modal, hope that makes sense. Here is some of my code.

```
 void _modalBottomSheetCustom(context)
  {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        isScrollControlled: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF8185E2),
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.9,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[

              new Align( 
                alignment: Alignment(-0.8,-0.8),
                child:
                   GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), // closing showModalBottomSheet
          child: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),)       
                ),
              new   Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 10,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: ModalPainter(),
          ),
        ),
              new Text("Date:", style: Theme.TextStyles.generalText),
              new Text("When do you want this service", style: Theme.TextStyles.generalText),
              new Text("We allow bookings up to 30 days in advance", style: Theme.TextStyles.generalText),
              new ChecklistWidget(),

              new Expanded(
                child:Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0.9,0.8),
                child:RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => _modalBottomSheetCustom2(context),
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                child: const Text('Next', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)), textColor: Colors.white,))),
            ],),

          );
        });
  }
```

_modalButtonSheetCustom2 is basically the same function as _modalButtonSheetCustom.

Hope my question makes sense to someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I didn't think it through I just put, Navigator.of(context).pop() before the code for the second modal and that seemed to work fine.